# Conditionally Format Coloring of Table in R

Tags: r, dataframe, gridextra, gtable, grob

Is there a way to conditionally format `tableGrob` cells/rows when using the `gridExtra` to export out PDFs? Based on conditional numeric values in a dataframe, I am hoping to change a row color background/fill formatting for my PDF output.

Sample Data:

```
 Name <- c('John','Adam','Jack')
 a <- c(1, 4, 3)
 b <- c(0, 6, 1)
 df1 <- data.frame(Name, a, b)
```

Right now I have a simple theme to format the output:

```
mytheme <- gridExtra::ttheme_default(
    core = list(fg_params=list(cex = 0.6),bg_params=list(fill=c("#FFFFFF", "#F8F8F8"))),
    colhead = list(fg_params=list(cex = 0.6)),
    rowhead = list(fg_params=list(cex = 0.6)))
```

This is my quick PDF output code:

```
 pdftitle=paste("Table-1.pdf",sep="")
  pdf(pdftitle,width=14, height=8)
  gridExtra::grid.table(df1,theme = mytheme, rows = NULL)
  dev.off()
```

The numerical values in column `a` and `b` from the sample data are actually successful and unsuccessful events. I'll end up quickly finding the success percentage and add that to my table for the output.

What I am hoping to achieve is the formatting of an entire row of the table in my PDF, so that any value greater than or equal to 50% from `df1` will be formatted in this color: `#C4122E` and if below 50%, formatted as `#1B458F`

Comment: [formattable](https://github.com/renkun-ken/formattable) is pretty nice, though there are other similar options, if you search a bit.

Comment: there are several ways to do it, have a look at https://github.com/baptiste/gridextra/wiki/tableGrob